# How to search for jsFiddles on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search, jsfiddle

Is there anyway that I can search for those of my questions that contain jsFiddle links? I would like to list all questions that contain a jsFiddle so that I would not waste time by checking all my questions. But the list of questions should only shows the titles of the questions.

Comment: Uh... what? Do you want to search for questions about jsFiddle?

Comment: This is... entirely unclear. What is it you're asking to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2138752+is%3Aquestion+url%3Ajsfiddle.net

Comment: Questions which include jsFiddle in Stackoverflow in my questions.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: @Asad - Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+is:question+url:jsfiddle.net (based on [Asad's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190972/how-to-search-for-jsfiddles-on-stack-overflow#comment593181_190972), but you can use `user:me` instead of having to figure out your ID)

For a list of search options, click on the *Advanced Search Tips* link on https://stackoverflow.com/search